# Python SQL Server timestamp in where clause using timedelta

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

Error when using timedelta from datetime.now() in SQL Server where clause

python 3.6

```
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)

sql = "SELECT submit_dt, api_job_name, job_status, xml_record_count, x_successful_number, x_failed_number, " \
      f"job_run_time, mf_job_name FROM JOB_LOG where submit_dt > {yesterday}"

try:
    db = Database()
    db.cursor.execute(sql)
    rows = db.cursor.fetchall()
```

> SQL ODBC Error: Incorrect syntax near '22' --- which is the time part of the datetime.

I've tried wrapping it in '' but then get convert from string error.

Answer (score 1):

Consider parameterizing your query without any need of string conversion of datetime or string interpolation including F-strings.

```
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)

sql = """SELECT submit_dt, api_job_name, job_status, xml_record_count, 
                x_successful_number, x_failed_number, 
                job_run_time, mf_job_name 
         FROM JOB_LOG 
         WHERE submit_dt > ?"""

try:
    db = Database()
    db.cursor.execute(sql, yesterday)
    rows = db.cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to including the microseconds in the compare value.  I was able to use:

```
yesterday_sql = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-$d %H:%M:%S")
```